# NLog slows down and breaks my ASP.net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, nlog

I have a library written in C# that performs various operations and uses `NLog` for logging. Currently, it is used in conjunction with a `WinForms` GUI to operate and everything works fine.

I have been asked to develop a new web-based interface to replace the old `WinForms` one, and I've chosen `ASP.net MVC5`.

The problem is that when I call ANY method from the library that logs something using `NLog`, my ASP.net application breaks: the load times between pages become extremely long (~30 seconds or so) and all status is lost (`TempData` and `ViewData` dictionaries are emptied).

But if I call the same exact method from the library after I commented all calls to `NLog` in that method, everything goes smoothly!

Why is this happening? Why is `NLog` killing my ASP.net MVC app?
Here's the NLog configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs\Service.log"  keepFileOpen="false" 
               layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
                  archiveFileName="logs\Service.{#}.log"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTES BEFORE YOU RUSH AND WRITE OBVIOUS SUGGESTIONS:**

- I'm not doing thousands of logs that would slow down the app. We're
  talking about a 15-20 log calls at best
- This only happens when logging to file. If, for example, I log to the network using xsi:type="NLogViewer" this problem does not occur

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue on the logging folder? Where is it hosted? Did you use something like ProcessMon (or diskmon or filemon) from sysinternals to see what is doing on with the I/O? What about how you are building up your log statements? Are you writing large strings using string concatenation to log? Are you using a lot of debug level logs with string formats that are not getting logged but still getting processed? Did you profile your web application to see where it is being slowed down using a profiling tool or the built in one in VS?

Comment: In short, **you** need to do some more investigative work OR supply a lot more information. No one but you can provide an answer with what is given as it would be a guess at best.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target

Comment: Do the logs actually succeed in writing to the file in the end?  Or is it perhaps some sort of internal NLog timeout failure you're seeing?

Comment: What's NLog's version?

Comment: @Igor: it's not a permission issue (tried running as admin). And as I wrote in the question, I'm not writing long logs / many logs. The profiling tool shows 0% cpu usage for about 30 seconds, then the call completes. It's not my app consuming resources... something else is "suspending" it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: no, NLog doesn't even attempt to create the log files! It fails/hangs before that

Comment: Right but if you use a profiler you can see what is causing it, internally. Personally I like dot.trace by Jetbrains. Once you have that you can better identify why it is happening and what you can do about it. Also is there any multithreading, simultanious writes to the log file, and are there any synchronization settings for nlog?

Comment: @Igor, thanks for your suggestions, I really appreciate it, but it turns out the issue was the one originally pointed out by Julian (see the accepted answer). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an issue here with the finding the base directory and so the full path is wrong.

If have seen these problems before in the past. For example, see [this issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1340)

Please use absolute paths or `${basedir}`.

Comment: You were correct! Using an absolute path completely fixed the issue! By the way... do you know if I can use an environmental variable in the path? I'd like to write to %ProgramData%\MyApp\Logs\ ... is there a way?

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 5):

Writing this as a further clarification, since the answer from Julian did indeed solve the problem, but I still didn't know **WHY** the problem was happening.

Since then, I found out, so here it goes:

basically, by not specifying an absolute path, the log file was being written in the applications working directory. In an ASP.net web app, this directory is the directory where the website is deployed on. This creates a huge problem: the site's main directory is constantly monitored by IIS in order to detect changes. When NLog writes the logfile to this directory, IIS detects a changed file, interprets it as the site being redeployed, and **restart the entire web application**.

So basically, at every new line of log, my app was being restarted from scratch! No wonder the performance was abismal!

TL;DR: don't write anything to the top-level directory where an ASP.net website is deployed.

Comment: I was doing the same mistake. +1 for adding the reason

Answer (score 3):

If performance is really important then consider changing from `<targets>` to `<targets async="true">`.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the logging I'm doing isn't very heavy, every method call usually adds no more than 10-20 log lines. The slowness was due to the problem pointed out by @Julian